# how to flush page data in python using mmap

Tags: python-3.6, fpga, mmap, xilinx, pci-e

I am trying to map a region of fpga memory to host system,

```
resource0 = os.open("/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:0b:00.0/resource0", os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
resource_size = os.fstat(resource0).st_size
mem = mmap.mmap(resource0, 65536, flags=mmap.MAP_SHARED, prot=mmap.PROT_WRITE|mmap.PROT_READ, offset= 0  )
```

If i flush my host page with
mem.flush()
then print the contents
the data is same as before,
nothing is getting cleared from page

```
print(mem[0:131072])
mem.flush()
print(mem[0:131072])
```

as i read on python mmap docs , it says it clears then content,
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html
but when i test it remains same
i am using python 3.6.9

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect flush to clear a page?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

> flush([offset, size])
>
> Flushes changes made to the in-memory copy of a file back to disk. Without use of this call there is no guarantee that changes are written back before the object is destroyed. If offset and size are specified, only changes to the given range of bytes will be flushed to disk; otherwise, the whole extent of the mapping is flushed. offset must be a multiple of the PAGESIZE or ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY.

So if you want to clear anything you have to assign a new value first and then write it to the memory i.e. flush it.

Comment: There's no point of flushing an mmio region like this. Just writing the desired value is enough to write it immediately to the FPGA. Doing mmap of sysfs-pci's resource0 maps the MMIO region directly without the page cache.

Comment: Thank you @haggai_e for your response, i wanted to clear a page, as i read all FFFFFFFF from my device, initially everything is working as expected, means i can write and read data back from fpga via pcie mmap, but eventually after some time it reads all FFFFFFFF from my registers which gave proper data earlier,so i though if i clear my page content would help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but reading 0xffffffff might indicate an error, or maybe something else changed the register state on the FPGA's side?